# Using resource bundles in servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, internationalization, resourcebundle

I have to load the properties files based on the locale and i have below code in my servlet.

```
ResourceBundle contactBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("/popproperties/impprops", request.getLocale());
```

also i created props file as below inside `popproperties` folder.

### impprops_en_US.properties

```
//some key value pairs here
```

Above code works fine without any issues. My question is i have only one porperties file as `impprops_en_US.properties`. If user changes browser settings from US to some other locale then there is no other corresponding locale's properties file. In such a case still i have to load `impprops_en_US.properties` file. How can i do that? do i need to create one more properties file as `impprops.properties`  ?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the documentation for i18n say? I'd guess it uses en_US by default, but I know that the docs specify the behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your code like if you are getting null/default on selecting a `default locale` then accordingly you can make a check and load the desired locale.
For ex ,In my case :

```
   String cc=req.getParameter("country");
   String ln=req.getParameter("language");
   Locale l=null;
   if(cc==null)
     l=new Locale("en","US");
   else
     l=new Locale(ln,cc);

   ResourceBundle rb=ResourceBundle.getBundle("ApplicationResources",l);
   req.setAttribute("resource", rb);
```